# A question on zero-dimensional space

Tags: general-topology

How to prove this claim:

> If $X$ is a Tychonoff space of cardinality $\omega_1 < 2^\omega$, then it is zero-dimensional.

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $x\in X$ and $U$ is an open nbhd of $x$. Since $X$ is Tikhonov, there is a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$ for all $y\in X\setminus U$. Let $A=f[U]\cap(0,1)$. Clearly $|A|\le|X|=\omega_1<2^\omega=|(0,1)|$, so we may choose $r\in(0,1)\setminus A$; what can you say about the set $f^{-1}\big[[0,r)\big]=\{y\in X:f(y)<r\}$?

**Added:** $[0,1)$ is open in $[0,1]$, and $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}\big[[0,r)\big]$ is open in $X$. Similarly, $[0,r]$ is closed in $[0,1]$, so $f^{-1}\big[[0,r]\big]$ is closed in $X$. But $r\in(0,1)\setminus A$, so there is no point $y\in X$ such that $f(y)=r$, and therefore ...

> ... $f^{-1}\big[[0,r)\big]=f^{-1}\big[[0,r]\big]$. Call this set $H$. $H$ is clopen, and $x\in H\subseteq U$. Since $x\in X$ was arbitrary, and $U$ was an arbitrary open nbhd of $x$, it follows that $X$ has a base of clopen sets and is therefore zero-dimension.

Comment: SORRY. I still can not follow you. What do you intend to do?

Comment: @Paul: I added the rest. A bit more of a hint is visible, and the conclusion of the argument is spoiler-protected.

Comment: It seems a little Wrong. By the definition of $f$, we can get that $X\setminus U \subset H$, so $H\cap U=\emptyset$, therefore it cannot $H\subset U$.

Comment: @Paul: No, $H\supseteq X\setminus U$, so $x\in X\setminus H\subseteq U$, the way I had it originally. But I’ve turned $f$ around, so that $f(x)=0$, and it works now.

Comment: @Paul: That is, there was a mistake, but it didn’t make $H\cap U$ empty; it meant that I wrote down the wrong one of the two complementary clopen sets $H$ and $X\setminus H$.

Comment: Thanks Brain. you are **HELPFUL**. I still have a question which puzzles me. Here is the link. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280425/if-x-is-a-compact-space-what-toplogical-properties-can-its-dense-left-separat

Comment: @Paul: That other question is pretty open-ended; I’ve been thinking about what can be said, but it would help if you could give some idea of the kinds of properties that most interest you.

Comment: In fact, I try to Know that such subspace can be discretely generated. A space $X$ is discretely generated if for every $A\subset X$ and every $x\in cl(A)$ there exists a discrete $D\subset A$ such that $x\in cl(D)$.

Comment: @Paul: Okay; I’ll give it some thought.